# Check if user is logged in or not django by username

Tags: python, django, validation, authentication

In django login, we can type `if request.user.is_authenticated` to check if the user is logged in.
But if we want to check the login status of a particular user by entering the username, we get the following:

```
#Python
def checkLoginStatus(username):
    #do some checks here....
    return True or False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django does not keep track of the login state of a user. It keeps track of:

- Whether a session is valid (not expired, exists in session store, etc)
- The last time a user authenticated itself and went from not logged in to logged in (via [`last_login`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.1.4/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L50)

If you want to keep track of it, you need to do it yourself:

- Add a [userprofile model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) with a nullable field `session_key`.
- Add [signal receivers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#topics-auth-signals) for logged_in and logged_out event.
- Upon logged_in event, get the session key from `request.session` (request is passed to the signal) and store it on the profile model
- Upon logged_out event, set the `session_key` to None
- Now you can implement an `is_logged_in` property that retrieves the session key for a user from its profile model and then checks if the session is still valid by getting the session from the `Session` model. If it's valid, the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query to get user that you want to check is_logged_in or not.

```
def checkLoginStatus(username):
    
    if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
        usr = User.objects.get(username=username)
        if usr.is_authenticated:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        print("No user exist with this {} username.".format(username))
        return False
```

Comment: The way `is_authenticated` is implemented, this will always return true. Only Anonymous users return False.

Comment: you are talking about  **request.user** but here we are using local variable  as **user**. But for on safe side, I am editing my answer to use different variable name.

Comment: [Orly](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.1.4/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L96)?

Comment: @Melvyn sure, will check it.

Comment: i tried it out...and as @Melvyn said... it always returned True... and only for anonymous users it returned False

Comment: ShashwatAgrawal @Melvyn thankyou for correcting me.  Melvyn should I remove my answer? As it is not appropriate.